# How can I simulate a laser sensor without hardware?

Tags: gazebo, rviz, laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone
I have downloaded hokuyo_node-hydro-devel in GitHub,and I want to simulate it in Gazebo or rviz. First I don't konw if Gazebo or rviz meet the requirements,which one should I choose? My Ubuntu is 12.04.Then,how to simulate the hokuyo sensor without hardware?Because Ijust want to see how the sensor works, make sure what I downloaded is what I need,then I can use the sensor somewhere else as a library.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152201/how-can-i-simulate-a-laser-sensor-without-hardware?/) by [ran95yu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13951/ran95yu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo is what you would use for simulation, rviz is only for displaying data.

However, this only simulates a laser with similar features. It will not simulate a physical hokuyo that you can virtually connect to. So you will not need the hokuyo_node at all. That is only for physical sensors. The interface for a laser is usually only messages.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ran95yu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13951/ran95yu/) on 2014-04-12**:
What you mean is that if I want to run hokuyo_node,I must connect physical sensors.Is it right?              And now how can I simulate a laser with similar features?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-13**:
You would use a plugin in gazebo that acts as a laser by sending the same message. See e.g. http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins